# Cannot change file to executable

Tags: android-source, selinux

I have the following file `/data/MyExec/Exec`.

I want to execute this file when the android device boots, therefore I created a service in `init.rc` that runs it.

The problem is that the file doesn't have execute permissions, so I also have to run `chmod +x` on the file before I execute it.

Because I run this file from `init.rc` I have to define `{ execute }` in a policy file, and I did.

The problem is that I can't define both `{ setattr }` and `{ execute }` for the same file.

How then can I make it executable and run it on boot?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to place the exec in `/bin/Exec`. Files there are automatically executable and there's no need to change their mode.

Comment: Yeah, also see info on the matter here: http://paldan.altervista.org/dir-and-files-permissions-in-the-aosp-filesystem/?doing_wp_cron=1474724093.3321709632873535156250

Comment: Omg! Altervista still exists! And thanks for the link :)